# How to use jextract to work with MacOS Framework header files?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, project-panama, jextract

I am looking at exploring Java's project Panama for use with some MacOS native programming. I got `jextract` built and running ([thanks to this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76918565/275347)).

There is a good doc site at https://foojay.io/today/java-panama-polyglot-part-3/ as well as a [GitHub repo with some samples](https://github.com/carldea/panama4newbies). However, I fail to get `jextract` working to generate sources for any of the MacOS frameworks.

I wonder if it's a matter of getting the includes correct?

Here is an example of what I tried:

```
jextract --source --output src -t org.unix \
        -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include \
        -I /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers \
      /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h
```

It fails with:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:54:10: fatal error: 'CoreFoundation/CFBase.h' file not found
```

I am a bit worried that this is a more complicated problem. MacOS examples typically import the framework headers files like this:

```
#import "CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h"
#import "Security/Security.h"
```

The layout of the frameworks in the SDK doesn't seem to make this easy.

Anyone has any examples of getting jextract and/or Panama working with MacOS Frameworks?

Comment: Not on Mac, but the OpenGL sample in the jextract repo uses a framework as well: https://github.com/openjdk/jextract/blob/master/samples/opengl/compilesource.sh it doesn't have a secondary include dir though. Do you have the `CFBase.h` file on your file system?

Comment: `CFBase.h` is in the same folder as `CoreFoundation.h`. It's a sibling. But the `#import CoreFoundation/...` part is confusing.